# Posting to FB using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I want to make a facebook post once a day using a ruby script and the Koala gem. I want to be able to set it up once and not have to keep changing the access toekns. After reading some posts and [Facebook documentation around Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) I implemented the following:

- Created a Facebook App
- Used the Graph API Explorer to get an access token for myself - this only lasts about 2 hours
- Used the following script to exchange the short term token for a long term token which lasts 2 months

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

- Wrote the following rake task to post to my Facebook wall

```
token = "CAAFlZAPhVBO8..."
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
@graph.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "My message!")
```

- Scheduled a rake command using [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)

With all of this setup, my script actually works! It writes to my wall every day based on the scheduler.

**My question is**: with this setup I will have to manually go and create a new short term access token using the graph api explorer and then use that to get the long term access token every two months. Also, I will have to go in and manually change the token = "blah blah" statement in y script. Can this be avoided at all? I have given the app I created the permission to post to my wall. Is there a way to automatically get the new access tokens within the script using Koala (or other gems/libs)?

Answer (score 0):

Once a user has given your app publish_actions permission, you can also use your app access token to publish wall posts in their name – you will just have to exchange `me` for the actual user id (because without a user access token the API can’t know who “me” is supposed to be).

And the combination `app_id|app_secret` (pipe symbol in the middle) can serve as app access token.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate and not hard code the short term token.
You can use omniauth-facebook gem to automate the omniauth login. Refer [Github](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook). Add this to your gemfile.

```
 gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
```

In config routes, match the callback

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback' => '[your controller]#[your function]'
```

Once you login successfully and land at the callback function, you will the token stored in the response in `request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]`

Use this token and exchange it with a long lived token each time the user logs in. You can safely assume that user logs in at least twice within the 60 days cap for long lived access token.

I am assuming you are using Ruby on Rails because you are using the Koala gem.